# NUnit and [SetUp] in base classes

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm looking at some test code using NUnit, which inherits from a base class containing a [SetUp] attribute:

```
public class BaseClass
{
   [SetUp]
   public void SetUp()
   {
     //do something
   }

}

[TestFixture]
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
  [SetUp]
  public void SetUp()
  {

   //do something else, with no call to base.SetUp()
  }
   //tests run down here.
   //[Test]
   //[Test]
   //etc
}
```

The derived class will certainly need the work done in the base class' SetUp() method.

Am I missing something, or will the SetUp() method in the base class not be called when the derived class's tests are run?  Is there something special with the [SetUp] attribute that ensures one will be called before the other?

Comment: Constructors are your friends. If you want an additive setup behavior - use the constructors, as their syntax is more intuitive for this. Also, you should also consider the rationale in http://jamesnewkirk.typepad.com/posts/2007/09/why-you-should-.html

Comment: Just another hint for anybody struggling with this issue: Make sure your `SetUp` methods are public. R# doesn't warn you if they are private but they won't run.

Comment: Up-to-date answer for NUnit 2.5+ here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22099351/532647

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can only have one `SetUp` method.

> A TestFixture can have only one SetUp method. If more than one is defined the TestFixture will compile successfully, but its tests will not run.
>
> http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setup&r=2.2.10

If you need to add additional setup logic in a child class, mark `SetUp` as virtual in your parent class, override it, and call `base.SetUp()` if you want the base class's setup to run, too.

```
public class BaseClass
{
   [SetUp]
   public virtual void SetUp()
   {
     //do something
   }

}



[TestFixture]
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
  public override void SetUp()
  {
   base.SetUp(); //Call this when you want the parent class's SetUp to run, or omit it all together if you don't want it.
   //do something else, with no call to base.SetUp()
  }
   //tests run down here.
   //[Test]
   //[Test]
   //etc
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  So it's the case that the code above is incorrect, and the base SetUp() method will not be called?

Comment: @larryq the code in your question is invalid because you have two methods in the inheritance chain with a [SetUp] attribute. The fix is to only have one method with SetUp and then override it as needed.

Comment: That's what I thought, thank you. (The code above was pasted from a project I've been working on, and I wondered if I'd missed something.)

Comment: This is not valid for nUnit >= 2.5, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22099351/2881450

Answer (score 88):

Before NUnit 2.5 the previous answers were correct; you could only have a single `[SetUp]` attribute for a test.

With NUnit 2.5 onwards you can have multiple methods decorated with the `[SetUp]` attribute.  Therefore the below is perfectly valid in NUnit 2.5+:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    [SetUp]
    public void BaseSetUp()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("BaseSetUp Called")
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    [SetUp]
    public void DerivedSetup()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("DerivedSetup Called")  
    }

    [Test]
    public void SampleTest()
    {
        /* Will output
         *    BaseSetUp Called
         *    DerivedSetup Called
        */
    }
}
```

When inheriting NUnit will always run the '[SetUp]' method in the base class first.  If multiple `[SetUp]` methods are declared in a single class NUnit cannot guarantee the order of execution.

[See here for further information](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setup&r=2.5).